# Best practice(Architectural level) to implement syncing the data back and forth from sever to android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I've a **Server application** running with data storage in **MySQL**.
Later some time, we happened to build a simple **Android app** for data updation to the server. So far so good.
But, Since with the issues we've been facing with network connectivity often, We wanted to maintain the data completely offline during poor network connectivity and sync it when there is proper network.

1) How I'm doing this is, Let's say if we have five tables in MySql from the server side, Then same tables with same structure I've build in **SQLite** in my Android App so that the user should able to use the app as if theresn't any difference. I've an additionlal independent table added in SQLite for offline updates which has to be synced.
2) Everytime I login into the app with proper network, I'm truncating all the tables in SQLite and fetching new fresh data from server and storing. So here, between login and landing page, since server has much data, data fetching and storing taking a lot of time in the app. Here I don't know any other way to achieve the performance.
So Here considering the above points, Is there a better way fetch the data from the server and sync with existed database in SQLite rather than truncating and restroring all the data from server?
I've been looking for the solution so eagerly. Please can someone helpout with good explanation or reference?

Comment: Try using some libraries like volley also that way you can use cached results or fetch data only if data is changed ..

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it in my app:

- store the last successful sync date on the device
- every object has a `lastUpdated` column
- deleted objects are not really deleted. They have a `isDeleted` flag
- sync all objects that have a `lastUpdated` >= your last sync date